# Circos error: REQUIRED MODULE IS MISSING

Tags: perl, clone, circos, cpanm

I clearly have `Clone` in my list of Perl modules. Why am I getting this error?

I am running Perl 5.16 on [Mac OS X v10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion).

```
lraven$ cat run.out

*** REQUIRED MODULE IS MISSING ***

You are missing the Perl module Clone. Use CPAN to install it as described in this tutorial

http://www.circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/configuration/perl_and_modules


lraven$ instmodsh
Installed modules are:
   App::cpanminus
   Bundle::NetSNMP
   Clone
   Config::General
   DBI
   ExtUtils::MakeMaker
   ...
```

I have tried re-installing from a .tar file, but I get the error:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr

There are many questions online about this error, but few solutions...

Comment: How did you install it? Sounds like you are trying to use a module that was installed with one version of Perl with another version of Perl.

Comment: As for your original error, you've provided absolutely no information about what gave the error

Comment: Thanks ikegami. There is no more information other than this. I try and run the example circos script and it tells me i need Clone. I checked - and it is installed. I installed Clone using cpanm. it is Clone version 0.36. 

Perl -v  gives version 5.16 and i saved the modules locally using
eval `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`

Comment: the information ikegami is referring to is: *what* produced run.out?

Comment: and is whatever it is also set up to look in local::lib?  sounds like maybe not.

Comment: oh sorry. The script to generate the test image is...

`#!/bin/bash
../bin/circos -conf etc/circos.conf -debug_group summary,timer > run.out`
I am not sure how to check what version of perl bin/circos is looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Finally got things to work using the command.

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Clone'
```

You may encounter some additional errors from missing Perl modules. In a few cases I could only install libraries from within the shell. These were (Font:TTF and Text::Format)

I installed these by running

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
>install Font:TTF
>install Text::Format
```